# What is wrong? TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Tags: python, pygame, typeerror

Could someone help me spot the error? I have no idead what I've done wrong.

This error only comes up when I'm inside the main.py and try to run the game.

Main Class:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from player import *
from blocks import *

gravity = -4

display_height, display_width = 640, 480
display = pygame.display.set_mode ((display_height, display_width), 0, 16)
pygame.display.set_caption("Pixie from Outerspace")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 30

player = Player(display_height/2)

levelOne = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
]

blockList = []

for y in range(0, len(levelOne)):
    for x in range(0, len(levelOne[y])):
        if (levelOne[y][x]==1):
            blockList.append(Block(x*32, y*32))

moveX, moveY = 0, 0

running = True

while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                if (event.type == pygame.QUIT):
                        running = False

                if (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN):
                    if (event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT):
                        moveX = 3
                    elif (event.key == pygame.K_LEFT):
                        moveX = -3

                    elif (event.key == pygame.K_d):
                        moveX = 10

                    elif (event.key == pygame.K_UP):
                        player.jump()

                if (event.type == pygame.KEYUP):
                    if (event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT):
                        moveX = 0
                    elif (event.key == pygame.K_LEFT):
                        moveX = 0

                    elif (event.key == pygame.K_d):
                        moveX = 0


        display.fill(pygame.Color("lightblue3"))

        for block in blockList:
            block.render(display)

        player.x += moveX
        player.y -= moveY

        player.update(gravity, blockList)
        clock.tick(FPS)
        pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Player Class:

```
import pygame

class Player(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = 60
        self.height = 56
        self.velocity = 0
        self.falling = True
        self.onGround = False
        self.pixie0 = pygame.image.load("pixie1.png")
        self.pixie1 = pygame.image.load("pixie2.png")
        self.timeTarget = 10
        self.timeNumber = 0
        self.currentImage = 0
        self.cloud = pygame.image.load("cloud.png")
        self.tree = pygame.image.load("tree.png")
        self.bush = pygame.image.load("bush.png")


    def jump(self):
        if (self.onGround == False):
            return
        self.velocity = 30
        self.onGround = False


    def detectCollision(self, x1, y1, w1, h1, x2, y2, w2, h2):
        if (x2 + w2 >= x1 >= x2 and y2 + h2 >= y1 >= y2):
            return True
        elif (x2 + w2 >= x1 + w1 >= x2 and y2 + h2 >= y1 >= y2):
            return True
        elif (x2 + w2 >= x1 >= x2 and y2 + h2 >= y1 + h1>=y2):
            return True
        elif (x2 + w2 >= x1 + w1 >= x2 and y2 + h2 >= y1 + h1>=y2):
            return True
        else:
            return False


    def update(self, gravity, blockList):

        if (self.currentImage == 0):
            self.currentImage += 1
        else: 
            self.currentImage == 0

        self.render()


        if (self.velocity < 0):
            self.falling = True

        collision = False

        blockX, blockY = 0, 0

        for block in blockList:
            collision = self.detectCollision(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height, block.x, block.y, block.width, block.height)

            if (collision == True):
                blockX = block.x
                blockY = block.y
                break

        if (collision == True):
            if (self.falling == True):
                self.falling = False
                self.onGround = True
                self.velocity = 0
                self.y = blockY - self.height

        if (self.onGround == False):
            self.velocity += gravity

        self.y -= self.velocity


    def render(self):
        display.blit (self.bush, (270, 367))
        display.blit (self.bush, (440, 367))
        display.blit (self.tree, (70, 232))
        display.blit (self.cloud, (150, 100))
        display.blit (self.cloud, (350, 50))
        display.blit (self.cloud, (450, 150))
        display.blit (self.cloud, (50, 50))

        if (self.currentImage == 0):
            display.blit(self.pixie0, (self.x, self.y))
        else:
            display.blit(self.pixie1, (self.x, self.y))
```

Comment: You said a `Player` needs `x` and `y`, then you try to create it with a single number. What did you expect?

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you exactly what is going on. The Player class expects two arguments when you instantiate it (as well as the automatically-passed "self"): `x` and `y`. But you instantiate it just with `display_height/2`, which is only one argument.

Rather than posting all that irrelevant code, you should have looked at the traceback that told you which line the error was happening on, and if you couldn't work out what was going on from that you should just post the relevant parts.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor of **Player** class, it takes 3 arguments clearly, one is self and other two , but you have only provided one parameter while initializing the object of the class, you need to provide y parameter too